# Assign value through OLEObjects

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to assign a value to an option button through .OLEobjects but I'm stuck as to what to do. Here's what I got

```
     with sheets.1
       For Each cOBtn In .OLEObjects
           posInstr = InStr(cOBtn.Name, "oBtn")
              If posInstr > 0 Then
                  cOBtn.Value = True
              End If
        Next
     end with
```

Obviously .Value doesn't work.. What should I put here?

Comment: Depends what the objects are ... try .Caption | .Text

Comment: @AlexK. it's a radio button, I'm trying to give it Value = True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
cOBtn.Object.Value = True
```

> Do you have any other activex control which has "oBtn" in it's name? –  Siddharth Rout 6 mins ago
>
> Yes, many of them; Also the same code (mine) works perfectly fine when I put for example .interior.Color instead of .value –  Jente van Heuverswyn 5 mins ago

In such a case ensure that you are actually working with an option button and nothing else :)

```
Sub Sample()
    With Sheet1
        For Each cOBtn In .OLEObjects
            posInstr = InStr(1, cOBtn.Name, "oBtn", vbTextCompare)

            If posInstr > 0 Then
                If TypeName(cOBtn.Object) = "OptionButton" Then
                    cOBtn.Object.Value = True
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Type mismatch for this one.

Comment: Are you sure it is an oleobject? Because the above code is tried and tested. Is it a form control or ActiveX Control?

Comment: Ehh not entirely but I guess so. It's an activeX control

Comment: Do you have any other activex control which has "oBtn" in it's name?

Comment: Yes, many of them; Also the same code (mine) works perfectly fine when I put for example .interior.Color instead of .value

Comment: Sigh, nevermind. I'm just stupid. I didn't reset my posInstr from a previous loop. After that your code did indeed work. My bad. I will mark this as correct when the timer is over. Edit: Actually that's kind of weird isn't it? Since I am writing a new value into posInstr anyway?

Comment: kool :) However see the update in my answer. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: Yes the `posinstr` should get reset :)