# Retrieving name and location of specific Shapes from worksheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is a follow up to my previous question ([Retrieving information of OLEObjects from Workbook with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830793/retrieving-information-of-oleobjects-from-workbook-with-vba))

**Scenario:** I am trying to retrieve data from a worksheet. The data might be normal strings or number or might be encased in check boxed (checked or not).

**Data example:**

```
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
| item1   | 2004  |                  |      |                  |
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
| value x | rfd   | checkbox for rfd |  nfd | checkbox for nfd |
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
| ident   | test7 | call3            |      |                  |
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
```

**Obs:** In this example the "checkbox for rfd/nfd" is a normal checkbox (either form or activex), and depending on the item in that sheet, either might be selected.

**Objective:** What I am trying to do is read the worksheet in 2 steps: First read all the data that is directly called, so I use the code:

```
Sub Test_retrieve()

' this will get all non object values from the sheet

Dim array_test As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

array_test = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j) = array_test(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

to get:

```
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
| item1   | 2004  |                  |      |                  |
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
| value x | rfd   |                  |  nfd |                  |
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
| ident   | test7 | call3            |      |                  |
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
```

Next I am trying to reach all the objectives/shapes in my worksheet. I used the following code to get name, value (checked of not) and location of all activex objects:

```
Sub getavticeboxvalue()

    ' this will get the names and values (as binary) of all the activex controlbox objects in the sheet

    Dim objx As Object
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1

    For Each objx In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).OLEObjects

        If objx.Object.Value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value = 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = objx.Name
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3).Value = objx.BottomRightCell.Address

        ElseIf objx.Object.Value = False Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value = 0
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = objx.Name
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3).Value = objx.BottomRightCell.Address
        End If
        i = i + 1

    Next objx

End Sub
```

Which yields something like:

```
+-------+-----------+----------+
| value | name      | location |
+-------+-----------+----------+
| 0     | checkbox1 | $C$2     |
+-------+-----------+----------+
| 1     | checkbox2 | $E$2     |
+-------+-----------+----------+
```

I would then proceed to feed the values (1s and 0s), to the first table, in the place where the checkboxes originally where (location).

**Issue:** When I try the same procedure for Form Control (instead of activex), I have less options, and although I can look for them (ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes.Type = 8) I cannot find their name or location.

**Question:** Is there a way to find their name and location? Is there a more efficient way to reach the result?

**Objective:**

```
+---------+-------+------------------+
| item1   | 2004  |       |      |   |
+---------+-------+------------------+
| value x | rfd   | 0     |  nfd | 1 |
+---------+-------+------------------+
| ident   | test7 | call3 |      |   |
+---------+-------+------------------+
```

Comment: Quick Note: `Sub Test_retrieve()` instead of storing it in an array and rewriting, you could have done it using `.Value = .Value` or even `pastespecial values`?

Comment: `Question: Is there a way to find their name and location? Is there a more efficient way to reach the result?` Yes there is the `.Object` method... I have answered similar post somewhere. Let me search for it

Comment: [One Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722961/assign-value-through-oleobjects/31723014#31723014)

Comment: [Another One](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?505132-RESOLVED-Iterating-Through-Controls&p=3112673&viewfull=1#post3112673)

Comment: Controls added through a Forms toolbar are considered shapes. So `Dim s as Shape` and loop through them like `For Each s in ActiveSheet.Shapes` should work. `s.Name` and `s.TopLeftCell.Address` and `s.BottomRightCell.Address` give you the same metadata.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I will go through the examples, many thanks.

Comment: @JvdV Name works perfectly, I will try to find one for location.